# Integral for Feynman diagrams with loops

Tags: integration

When I encounter Feynman diagram with loops, I have momentum integrals of the form:

$$ \int d^{4}k\ k^{D-4}$$

And apparently it can be shown that it is equivalent to an integral of the form:

$$ \int dk\ k^{D-1}$$

But I don't really understand that step. Is it by using some type of hyperspheric coordinates ?

Comment: $d^4 \vec{k} = dk k^3 d\Omega_3$ where $k=|\vec{k}|$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a relativistic non-Euclidean variant on hyperspheres, yes. Working in polar coordinates, $d^4k=k^3dkd\Omega$, where $\int d\Omega$ just multiplies things by a constant because all functions are of the polar coordinate $k$ only, so are angle-independent. Thus $\int d^4kf\left( k\right)\propto\int dkk^3f\left( k\right)$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes: the volume element in $d$ dimensions is (cf. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Closed_forms))
$$
\mathrm d^dk=\frac{2\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(d/2)}k^{d-1}\mathrm dk
$$
so that, in $d=4$, we get
$$
\mathrm d^4k=2\pi^2k^3\mathrm dk
$$

This means, in particular, that
$$
\int\mathrm d^4k\ k^{D-4}f(k)=2\pi^2\int \mathrm dk\ k^{D-1}f(k)
$$